# Which quantum numbers does the orbital angular momentum depend on?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, atomic-structure

I learned from a question that I recently solved that the orbital angular momentum depends on both the azimuthal and magnetic quantum numbers.

I did not expect this because the formula for the orbital angular momentum is $ \sqrt{l(l+1)} \frac {h}{2π} $ and so I expected it to only depend on the azimuthal quantum number.

So, why does orbital angular momentum depend on the magnetic quantum number? A detailed explanation will be appreciated.

Comment: What keeps you from searching for what the magnetic quantum number is about? // The site expects that you write explicit compact summary of your prior effort to answer the question, based on your knowledge and on searching for existing related  info or answers. It would prevent others to tell you what you already know or what you could easily find yourself.

Comment: @Poutnik I can't find a detailed and understandable explanation online.

Comment: Try harder and describe what you have tried.

Comment: @Poutnik I tried "why does the orbital angular momentum depend on the magnetic quantum number" on google. That's the most I can do.

Comment: You can do much more than you say you can. See Wikipedia page for magnetic quantum number. You have nice picture there illustrating relation of orbital angular momentum and magnetic quantum number.

Comment: Note that relation of magnetic quantum number to orbital angular momentum is  the same as relation of spin quantum number to spin angular momentum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Orbital angular momentum*, like any other form of angular momentum, is a vector quantity.* Thus, it has both a magnitude as well as a direction.

The *magnitude* of the orbital angular momentum is given by the formula you wrote, and is thus only dependent on the quantum number $l$:

$$|L| = \hbar\sqrt{l(l+1)}.$$

However, the *orientation* of the angular momentum vector is partly described by the quantum number $m$. In particular, the $z$-component of the orbital angular momentum is given by

$$L_z = m\hbar.$$

It's a quirk of quantum mechanics, however, that you can't simultaneously know all three components $(L_x, L_y, L_z)$, so this is the best we can really do. Ultimately, this is because the operators $L_x, L_y, L_z$ don't commute with one another.

So, given that we know the magnitude $|L|$ as well as the $z$-component $L_z$, we can say that the orbital angular momentum lies somewhere along a *cone*, as the following picture from Atkins' *Molecular Quantum Mechanics* (4th ed.) shows. Atkins uses the general symbol $I$ to refer to some kind of angular momentum; the fact that it's orbital angular momentum doesn't change anything. Indeed, the [Wikipedia page on magnetic quantum number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_quantum_number) has a very similar picture, as pointed out in the comments.

[image: angular momentum cone]

---

* Pseudovector, for the picky.

Comment: *Pseudovector, for the picky.* I was always humbled by my naive chemist approach to vectors in Usenet sci.physics and sci.physics.relativity in the past. Pseudovectors, covariant vectors, contravariant vectors, "not at all" vectors.... Oh my, the good old classic of old time volumetry. :-)

Comment: @Poutnik To be honest, I don't profess to understand it anywhere near as well as the physicists do ;) They talk about dual spaces and Hodge stars and something like that. To me, it's just called "reflect it in a mirror and it changes"!